# Android Application Help

Tags: java, android, notifications

Hi I have created a task reminder application.  However I am unable to get it to notify the user of the task with the task name. It should be a fairly simple thing to do, but I am unable to do it.

What I want it to do is: I save a task called "Task 3" and to remind me for 6pm. When 6pm comes, I get a notification alert saying "Task 3". At the moment, it only says "task needs to be reviewed"  Is there a way of  retrieving the task title and presenting it as a notification instead of a string?

This is the reminder service class class:

public ReminderService() {
        super("ReminderService");
            }

```
@Override
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class);                 
    notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

//This is the bit I need to change by the way.

```
    Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
```

and this is the remindersadapter class

```
* @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime); 

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all reminders
 */
public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
 * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder date time
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to update
 * @param title value to set reminder title to
 * @param body value to set reminder body to
 * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time. 
 * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you display a constant string defined in your string.xml. You should use the row id you get from the Intent to fetch the corresponding reminder from you database and display its title.

Once you retrieve the cursor from your fetchReminder method while providing the row id, you can get the title of your reminder using:

```
String reminderTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
```

Verify that your cursor is not null beforehand.

Comment: HI that's correct.  I have tried using the row id, but it for some reason wont show the title, just the word "id".

Comment: Hi thank you.  Does the String reminderTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
    go inside the fetchreminder method?

Comment: No, you have to call the ReminderDbAdapterfetchReminder method with the row id as a parameter when you build your notification. It will return you a cursor on the corresponding database record and then you can gwt the title using the line of code I gave you.